# Чтение атрибута HTML-тега из php файла с помощью ajax

Tags: ajax, php

Приветствую всех.

Есть функция, которая каждые 10 секунд подгружает из php-файла строки из базы данных.
Также, прописан тестовый HTML-тег, который в дальнейшем будет служить для удаления записей из БД.

```
echo '<a href="#" id="test">X</a>';
```

Попробовал сделать так:

```
        $(function() {
            $("#test").click(function() {
                alert("тест");
            }); 
        });
```

Не реагирует. Подскажите, в чем проблема? (Необходимо прочитать HTML-атрибут из другого файла)

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: не надо наверное id использовать здесь, а так:

    $(document).on('click','#test',function(){})

вместо document используйте элемент, который не меняется js и является предком #test

Comment: $("#test").on('click','#tested',function(){
    alert("test");
});

echo "<div id='test'><button id='tested'>тест</button></div>";

Спасибо за ответ, попробовал так, ничего не вышло. Напомню, что чтение идет из другого файла.

Comment: Как вы прогружаете с php?